# Db2 Connectivity issue - Database not found

Tags: azure-functions, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm trying to connect to DB2 using Azure function app, getting the following error:
ERROR [08004] [IBM] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "DATABASE         " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004.

Code:
DB2Connection dB2Connection = new DB2Connection("DATABASE=DATABASE;server=XX.XX.XX.XX:446;UID =ID;PWD=PASSWORD");
dB2Connection.Open();

And I'm able to connect and see the database in DBvisualizer.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Refer this Document - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql30061n-received-when-db2-client-connects-remote-db2-database-server-due-another-application-using-same-port-number-db2-listener

Comment: Dbvis is using jdbc, but you are trying to connect with ODBC (not jdbc). The two protocols do not share code.  The simplest explanation is that your database-name is not correct.  Your Db2 DBA will also be able to give more details about what gets logged at the Db2-server end, so ask that person.

Comment: Is your target database on i-series (as400) ?  Please tag your question with the correct Db2-server platform (db2zos, db2400, db2luw)

Comment: @mao, yes, its as400

Comment: Always use the correct rdbms tags when asking for help. You should also mention the exact VERSION of the i-series (ask your admin for help). Try omitting DATABASE=DATABASE; from the connection string to see if there is a configured default.  Otherwise talk with your admin to see the database-names (they will also be visible in your ibm i access gui if you have it installed).